# Programmatically changing the WinXP language

Tags: localization, windows-xp

How do I programmatically change the language used in WinXP using .Net 2.0 (or a pInvoke). The user does not have access to the task bar in the application I'm working on so the input method needs to reflect the application's selected language. I need to be able to swap the language from a left-to-right to a right-to-left and back again without restarting the application. Controls can be re-created though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language should be installed in the system, check the following code it's to change the language into Arabic in C#:

```
public void ToArabic()
    {
        string CName= "";
        foreach(InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages) 
        {
            CName = lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToString();

            if(CName.StartsWith("Arabic"))
            {
                InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
            }
        }

    }
```

to return it back into English

```
public void ToEnglish()
        {
            string CName= "";
            foreach(InputLanguage lang in InputLanguage.InstalledInputLanguages) 
            {
                CName = lang.Culture.EnglishName.ToString();

                if(CName.StartsWith("English"))
                {
                    InputLanguage.CurrentInputLanguage = lang;
                }
            }

        }
```

you can use this code in your application to change the input language.
Also the user can press alt + shift to change between the defined language in the system.